# How to use an interface type as @Prop() type in stenciljs component?

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

I have an interface like that:

```
export default interface PostRecord{
...
}
```

and a stencil js component like this:

```
export class Container implements ComponentInterface {

@prop record: PostRecord;

...
}
```

with a correct import of PostRecord.
Then the typescript compiler complains:

```
[ ERROR ] TypeScript: ./src/components.d.ts:29:19
[0] Cannot find name 'PostRecord'.
[0]
[0] L28: "active": boolean;
[0] L29: "record": PostRecord;
[0] L30: }
```

Is it possible to use interface types as property types or what is wrong with the picture?

- @stencil/core": "1.16.2"

Thank you for your help.
Lutz

Comment: How are you importing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using a default export for the interface. You should try switching to a named export, i. e.

```js
export interface PostRecord {
  // ...
}
```

and then import it as

```js
import { PostRecord } from './post-record';
```

(instead of `import PostRecord from './post-record';`).

Otherwise Stencil will not be able to determine where the interface is exported because it can't be looked up by name.

Comment: I don't think this is in the docs, but imo named exports are generally preferable anyway... try searching Google for "are default exports bad" 